# need inputs to change the date pattern using python regsub

Tags: python

I am using the below reg.sub to change the date format from yyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyy . But the new date format also comes in the original format and does not change.Can you please point me what I am missing here?

```
def dateextract1(dt):
return re.sub(r'(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/', '\\3-\\2-\\1', dt)

dt1 = "2026-01-02"
print("Original date in YYY-MM-DD Format: ",dt1)
print("New date in DD-MM-YYYY Format: ",dateextract1(dt1))
```

=======================

```
Original date in YYY-MM-DD Format:  2026-01-02
New date in DD-MM-YYYY Format:  2026-01-02   [ I would expect : 02-01-2026]
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason for using RegEx for this? The [Python datetime library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) has a pretty effective date formatter.

Comment: Just having hands on regEx in python...so was curious to know why this is not working here